# Would it be possible to overload << operator for a std::map with pair std:string and std::vector<int>?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, stdmap

I previously overloaded the `<<` operator for a `std::map` using `template` for a `std::map<std::string, int>`

```
template <typename T, typename S> 
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const std::map<T, S>& v) 
{ 
    for (auto it : v)  
        os << it.first << " : " << it.second << "\n"; 

    return os; 
}
```

How can a template be written if the `map`, for instance, was `std::map< std::string, std::vector<int> >`?

Comment: Not at all, but instead add overloaded operator for `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4850473/1870232)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options for.

At first you could just provide a separate `operator<<` overload for `std::vector`, e. g.:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, std::vector<T> const& v)
{ /* your generic implementation */ return s; }
```

It will then be called for every vector in your map:

```
os << it.first << " : " << it.second << "\n";
//                           ^ here...
```

I consider this the cleanest solution – but if it is *too* generic and you need something really different only for this specific map type, then you could either provide a separate overload for exclusively this type of map:

```
std::ostream& operator<<
        (std::ostream& s, std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> const& m)
{ /* your specific implementation */ return s; }
```

or, alternatively, specialise your operator for it:

```
template <>
std::ostream& operator<< <std::string, std::vector<int>>
        (std::ostream& s, std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> const& m)
{ /* your specific implementation */ return s; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes, you could write the code.

Is it allowed? No, it's undefined behavior to extend the `std` namespace with your own symbols unless explicitly specified.

Looking at your current approach, I wouldn't overload the existing method. I would provide a new method for the pair.

Comment: Where would we extend `std` namespace if we provide additional overloads in global namespace? Apart from, this is only half of the truth, as there is an exception: it is allowed to specialise existing templates within namespace `std`.

Comment: To get the ADL correct, you have to define the operator in std. No, it is only allowed to specialize when explicitly permitted, like `std::hash`, you can't do so for `std::basic_string`

Comment: If we rely on ADL, already the initial template fails - but if defined in global namespace, we do not rely on...